# How Javascript Parsing the syntax

Tags: javascript

Actually, a statement like.,

```
    for (var i = 0, ; i < row; i++,) {}
```

makes the `*.js` to not load in the browser. In C/C++ its a easy to find, syntax error. 
But here it took me 20 mins to trace this bug happened accidentally in my  cut/copy/paste.

My Question : 
  Often I am facing this issue., when and why this issue occurs? How to find that easily.

Comment: You should always have the javascript console opened.

Comment: Chrome development tools, Firebug, etc.

Comment: @sza in Javascript `console` too no  error will not be showed. In `script` page, the js file other than this one are loading up.

Comment: @VisioN in Javascript console too no error will not be showed. In script page, the js file other than this one are loading up.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT it will show up. Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/WNSm2/

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT You should switch browser. I know for certain that this script will cause a SyntaxError in Google Chrome. Also, is it possible that your scripts are loaded through some sort of 'loader' library that is improperly squelching the error? (Try directly including your script in the HTML, with the above syntax issue; see if you get a console error)

Comment: Use IDE's to write code.. Netbeans, Coda 2, etc... (not notepad++ gg..)

Comment: @JohnnyJS Notepad++ is the best IDE after Notepad and GNU nano ;)

Comment: @sza I am not getting error in console tab. I am using firefox/OpenSuse 12.0

Comment: @VisioN: I like me some [Geany](http://geany.org/).  Also I like Vim :)

Comment: @VisioN yep.. (i guess you code throw vim on terminal gg..) simple ide' are cool. but will not show you scary red flags, when you doing syntax errors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments on your question say, use development add-ons in browsers. I can only speak for firefox, but there are a bunch of great tools available.

For firefox, the normal debug console is useful for much of what you need to debug and test, it can do validation on much of the content that firefox is displaying/running.

For some things that are slightly out of the debug consoles reach, I use Firebug. It can do anything I need to inspect, even look at all the headers and responses of ajax requests.

I know Chrome has some developer tools, and I bet there are some great add-ons out there for it too.

These tools make things go much faster than using alert('spot1') ... alert('spot2') debugging techniques. They even give you line numbers for syntax errors.

Comment: Can't speak for firefox, but chrome's dev tools are awesome even without plugins of any kind ;-)